# PhysicalNamingStrategy bean only instantiates via config file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a custom naming strategy in a Spring app with Hibernate:

```
public class MyCustomPhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {

  @Override
  public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
    return Identifier.toIdentifier("my_custom_table_name");
  }

  // ...

}
```

[The Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy) says I can tell Hibernate to use it either by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` (which works fine), or like this:

> Alternatively, if `ImplicitNamingStrategy` or `PhysicalNamingStrategy` beans are available in the application context, Hibernate will be automatically configured to use them

I need to use this second method, as I need to pass some info from Spring's context to my naming strategy. However, I can't get it to work.

I'm creating the bean in the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public PhysicalNamingStrategy physicalNamingStrategy() {
    return new MyCustomPhysicalNamingStrategy();
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I'm on Spring Boot/Spring JPA 1.5.9.RELEASE, which gives me Hibernate core v.5.0.12.Final and Hibernate JPA API 2.1.

Comment: That's an interesting question. Could you please add exact version numbers of (a) Spring (boot) and (b) Hibernate to your question?

Comment: Good catch @MWiesner. I added the versions to the post. I'm on Spring Boot/Spring JPA 1.5.9.RELEASE, which gives me Hibernate core v.5.0.12.Final and Hibernate JPA API 2.1.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. The bean gets loaded properly by spring (I see system outs appearing when I put the in the @Bean method), but hibernate seems to completely ignore them. I'm using the exact same versions as Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is only supported with spring boot 2.

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.java#L95

This file is not present in spring boot 1.5: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.14.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa

(`HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java` doesn't have it)

Comment: Good catch, @nsv. Thanks. Just for reference if others get here with the same issue, here is the documentation for naming strategies in version 1.5.9.RELEASE: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy