# SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy with configurable suffix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, orm

We would like to accomplish a double run setup  in which our application writes data in a table of which the table name is a composition of the JPA-configured table name and an arbitrary affix.

Our application uses Spring Boot with Spring ORM backed by Hibernate.

The suffix should be easily configurable, ideally via Spring Boot's externalized configuration.

Following is our SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy implementation that appends the suffix to table name. The suffix is currently hardcoded.

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

@Component
public class DoubleRunPhysicalNamingStrategy extends SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {

    private Set<String> tableNames = new HashSet<>(asList("AR", "AP"));

    private String suffix = "_2";

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        Identifier identifier =
                super.toPhysicalTableName(name, jdbcEnvironment);

        if (tableNames.contains(identifier.getText().toUpperCase())) {
            return new Identifier(String.format("%s%s", identifier.getText(), suffix), identifier.isQuoted());
        }

        return identifier;
    }

}
```

Finally, above physical naming strategy is configured via following application property:
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=DoubleRunPhysicalNamingStrategy

We tried using @Value and another component via @Autowired to make the suffix configurable but without luck. Both are not wired and stay unassigned.

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhysicalNamingStrategy bean only instantiates via config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058013/physicalnamingstrategy-bean-only-instantiates-via-config-file)

Comment: Indeed, tnx! Unfortunately upgrading to Spring Boot 2.0 is not an option at the moment.

Not directly seeing an easy workaround.

Comment: Well as a work around you can configure your class with plain old system properties(-Dsuffixes=s1,s2). You can create a static "holder" class that gives you access to the ConfigurableApplicationContext, which will give you access to Spring properties via "getEnvironment()" method. You can read "application.properties" or some other properties file using standard "java.lang.Properties".... You have a few "workarounds" here :)